# Progress dialog in imageview until i load image from server

Tags: android, android-spinner

How can I add the `Progress dialog` in `ImageView` until I loading image from server in android. When image download complete then display the image.

```
try {
    cachedImage = imageLoader.loadImage(mTopicList.getTopicImage(j), 
        new ImageLoadedListener() {
            public void imageLoaded(Bitmap imageBitmap)
            {
                imageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
                imageView.invalidate();
            }
        });

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: You should consider `AsyncTask` class to do this.

Comment: @TGMCians did you solve this? Progress dialog in ImageView until the loading of image is complete.

Comment: @TGMCians what you mean by apply progress dialog for complete screen? U mean one single progress bar to view pager?

Comment: Can you please post your answer/solution code here, otherwise it is not going to help others

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Approach which I followed to do this. Use the Frame Layout and have a `ImageView` and `ProgressBar` inside it. I've used the Universal Image Loader Library, which have callback once image has been downloaded. Initially show the `ProgressBar` and hide the `ImageView` to invisible. Once image has been downloaded then hide the `ProgressBar` and show the image in the `ImageView`.

Initially

```
imageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Load your image now. After loading it, call this:

```
progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Hope this help to you all!